Tensorflowのモデルによる学習途中の確認方法は？
現在Tensorflowにて時系列データを予測しようとしております。
いろいろ触っているうちに学習過程の中身を知りたくなりました。
とくにCovd1d層とLSTM層について知りたいです。
具体的には各エポック内で、どのトレーニングデータが渡され、そしてそのトレーニングデータに対してどの予測結果を出しているのか、予測結果に対応したテストデータは何かです。
初学者のため、不明瞭な質問かもしれませんが教えていただけると幸いです。
どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。
model = tf.keras.Sequential()

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, padding="same", activation="relu",
                                 input_shape=(x_train.shape[1], x_train.shape[2]), kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size=1))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=256, kernel_size=3, padding="same", activation="relu",
                                 kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size=1))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=512, kernel_size=3, padding="same", activation="relu",
                                 kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size=1))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units=256, activation="tanh", return_sequences=False, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=128, activation="relu"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, activation="linear"))

model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001), loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(),
              metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.MeanAbsoluteError()])

model.summary()

callbacks = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor="loss", min_delta=0.0001, patience=15)
validation_data = (x_valid, y_valid)
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=200, batch_size=2048, validation_data=validation_data, callbacks=[callbacks], verbose=1)

mse, mae = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
print(f"MSE(test): {mse}")
print(f"MAE(test): {mae}")

y_pred = model.predict(x_test)

